# Hibernate SequenceGenerator returning incorrect nextval

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence-generators

This is my second post about hibernate. Since I started using hibernate it has given more problems than the problems it has solved. It almost makes me feel like I should have stuck to plain old JDBC. Anyway,

Here is one of the problems I'm trying to battle.

My Sequence generator in the .hbm files looks as follows.

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">ADVENTURES_ID_SEQ</param>
        <param name="allocationSize">1</param>
        <param name="initialValue">17599</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Please note: initial value is 17599. This is because LAST_NUMBER in the oracle sequence is: 17599

```
CREATED         25-APR-12
LAST_DDL_TIME   25-APR-12
SEQUENCE_OWNER  ADVENTURE_ADMIN
SEQUENCE_NAME   ADVENTURES_ID_SEQ
MIN_VALUE       1
MAX_VALUE       9999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG      N
ORDER_FLAG      N
CACHE_SIZE      20
LAST_NUMBER     17599
```

When I run the code I see the next sequence generated as 200, 201 in the Hibernate Debug statement.

```
DEBUG SQL - select ADVENTURES_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual
DEBUG SequenceGenerator - Sequence identifier generated: 201
```

I expected the nextval should have been 17600. Seems like the oracle sequence is not getting used at all.

What is wrong in my configuration and how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does it generate if you run `select ADVENTURES_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual` on the same database?

Comment: It gives the correct value 17584, 17585, 17586 etc. Our DBA told us information table can sometime show the incorrect value which is 17599 in this case. This incorrect value is because they(Oracle) do some shortcuts to calculate the information and it should only be used as a guideline.

Comment: I had a similar problem, maybe some user may be interested. Upgrading from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5, something has changed. In Hibernate 3 I never wrote the "allocationSize" parameter, and everything worked. In Hibernate 5 I had to specify allocationSize=1. I am using annotations, not hbm files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self Answer (Workaround): I'm still seeing the issue but for now I have a workaround. Since it worked for me I'm selecting the question as complete.

I'm letting Oracle generate the nextId using Trigger:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER ADVENTURE_ADMIN.ADVENTURES_ID_TRIG 
BEFORE INSERT ON ADVENTURE_ADMIN.ADVENTURES FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT ADVENTURES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM DUAL;  
END;
```

Then I'm letting hibernate use the Oracle Trigger generated ID. There are two ways of doing this.

**First** is by using Hibernate [select](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id). Disadvantage of this approach is you will need another column in the table with unique constraint which is used by the hibernate as a key to fetch the row. It doesn't really work for me as I have tables with primary key as the only unique key.

**Second** is by using TriggerAssignedIdentityGenerator created by Jean-Pol Landrain, Martin Zeltner. Source could be found [here](https://el4j.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/el4j/branches/el4j_3_1/el4j/framework/modules/hibernate/src/main/java/ch/elca/el4j/services/persistence/hibernate/TriggerAssignedIdentityGenerator.java). This has enabled me to get around the problem of finding another unique key for the table.

Following is how I'm using it:

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
    <generator class="org.hibernate.id.TriggerAssignedIdentityGenerator" />
</id>
```

Please Note: Hibernate version you are using matters. I'm using 3.5.4. hibernate 3.6 didn't work for me. JDBC and Oracle Driver version also matters. You can refer to the documentation in the source file for the same.

Comment: Glad my id generator helped you !

You can find the original post related to this generator on Hibernate forums. It's rather old now, but the contributions from many people are keeping it alive even with Hibernate 4.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973262

Comment: @n00bc0der have you found the reason about your problem?